# CSS height 100% not working in ipad browser

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, ipad

I have tried to set equal height columns for my feature collection. Its everything working good in desktop and mobile ipad screens . But when I check real device the `height:100%`not working. I have tried 'height:100vh` also.

```
<div class="feature-category default-padding bg-white">
    <div class="full container">
        <div class="cartHomeTitle text-center mb-4">
            <h3>Featured Collection</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="row mycolspce">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="feature-imgitem d-flex align-self-stretch h-100">
                    <a class="banner_effect" href="#">
                        <img src="img/new-product1.jpg" class="img-fluid w-100" alt="fc-collection">
                    </a>
                    <div class="fc-meta">
                        <h4>Men</h4>
                        <p>New Collection</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="feature-imgitem">
                    <a class="banner_effect" href="#">
                        <img src="img/fc-collection2.jpg" class="img-fluid w-100" alt="fc-collection">
                    </a>
                    <div class="fc-meta left">
                        <h4>Shirts</h4>
                        <p>8 Item</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row mt-4">                  
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="feature-imgitem">
                            <a class="banner_effect" href="#">
                                <img src="img/fc-collection3.jpg" class="img-fluid w-100" alt="fc-collection">
                            </a>
                            <div class="fc-meta left">
                                <h4>Bags</h4>
                                <p>8 Item</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="feature-imgitem">
                            <a class="banner_effect" href="#">
                                <img src="img/fc-collection4.jpg" class="img-fluid w-100" alt="fc-collection">
                            </a>
                            <div class="fc-meta">
                                <h4>SALE</h4>
                                <p>FASHION SHOES</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </div> <!--//container-->
</div>
```

[my webiste url Featured Collection](http://orderonline.my/demo.mybizcart/)

My ipad this what I am getting as per below image.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes `height` and `min-height` will not work on ipad and safari browsers. You can use `display:flex` follow flexbox group to align **equal column height** as below example.

```css
.row.mycolspce div[class^="col-"] {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.feature-imgitem img {
  object-fit:cover;
}
.feature-imgitem,.banner_effect {
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
      <div class="row mycolspce">
          <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="feature-imgitem">
                  <a class="banner_effect" href="#">
                      <img src="http://orderonline.my/demo.mybizcart/img/new-product1.jpg" class="img-fluid w-100" alt="fc-collection">
                  </a>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="feature-imgitem">
                  <a class="banner_effect" href="#">
                      <img src="http://orderonline.my/demo.mybizcart/img/fc-collection2.jpg" class="img-fluid w-100" alt="fc-collection">
                  </a>
              </div>
              <div class="row mt-4">                  
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                      <div class="feature-imgitem">
                          <a class="banner_effect" href="#">
                              <img src="http://orderonline.my/demo.mybizcart/img/fc-collection3.jpg" class="img-fluid w-100" alt="fc-collection">
                          </a>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                      <div class="feature-imgitem">
                          <a class="banner_effect" href="#">
                              <img src="http://orderonline.my/demo.mybizcart/img/fc-collection4.jpg" class="img-fluid w-100" alt="fc-collection">
                          </a>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```